# regex works, but not in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex:

```
.+?(=*)(myarray\()\{([\S| \|'.,]*)},\s*(\p{L}+)(.*\*\d+)
```

Which searches this string and matches the different parts shown here:

```
blahb.blah = myarray({-68,-67,-65,-62,-61,-59,-58,-56,-55,-53,-52,-51,-49,-48,-47,-46,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-39,-38,-37,-36,-35,-34,-33,-32,-31,-30,-29,-29,-28,-27,-26,-26,-25,-24,-24,-23,-22,-22,-21,-21,-20,-20,-19,-19,-19,-18,-18,-18,-17,-17,-17,-16,-16,-16,-15,-15,-15,-14,-14,-14,-14,-13,-13,-13,-12,-12,-12,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-9.7,-9.4,-9.1,-8.8,-8.5,-8.2,-7.9,-7.5,-7.2,-6.9,-6.6,-6.3,-6,-5.7,-5.3,-5,-4.7,-4.4,-4.1,-3.8,-3.4,-3.1,-2.8,-2.5,-2.2,-1.9,-1.6,-1.2,-0.9,-0.6,-0.3,0,0.3,0.6,1,1.3,1.6,1.9,2.2,2.5,2.9,3.2,3.5,3.8,4.1,4.4,4.7,5.1,5.4,5.7,6}, x*456, 1);
```

https://regex101.com/r/frF0eC/7

However, when I try to run this same regex in python, it doesnt work. I'm wondering why? Is there something about python that's different to other regex systems?

Heres an example of the Python code:

```
import re
myarray = " blahb.blah = myarray({-68,-67,-65,-62,-61,-59,-58,-56,-55,-53,-52,-51,-49,-48,-47,-46,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-39,-38,-37,-36,-35,-34,-33,-32,-31,-30,-29,-29,-28,-27,-26,-26,-25,-24,-24,-23,-22,-22,-21,-21,-20,-20,-19,-19,-19,-18,-18,-18,-17,-17,-17,-16,-16,-16,-15,-15,-15,-14,-14,-14,-14,-13,-13,-13,-12,-12,-12,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-9.7,-9.4,-9.1,-8.8,-8.5,-8.2,-7.9,-7.5,-7.2,-6.9,-6.6,-6.3,-6,-5.7,-5.3,-5,-4.7,-4.4,-4.1,-3.8,-3.4,-3.1,-2.8,-2.5,-2.2,-1.9,-1.6,-1.2,-0.9,-0.6,-0.3,0,0.3,0.6,1,1.3,1.6,1.9,2.2,2.5,2.9,3.2,3.5,3.8,4.1,4.4,4.7,5.1,5.4,5.7,6}, asd*456, 1); "

matchObj = re.search( r".+?(=*)(myarray\()\{([\S| \|'.,]*)},\s*(\p{L}+)(.*\*\d+)", myarray)

print matchObj
print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group()
print "matchObj.group(1) : ", matchObj.group(1)
print "matchObj.group(2) : ", matchObj.group(2)
```

Here is an online example of the Python script: https://repl.it/EtP8/1

For some reason it is searching and returning None? Any idea why?

Comment: Select Flavor = Python in regex101 and you will see that it doesnt work there either. I do not know why but it will help you find the error.

Comment: The re module doesn't have unicode character classes like `\p{L}`. If you really need this class, use the regex module instead. (otherwise replace it with `[a-zA-Z]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your python code has error, the haystack string contains "myarray" whereas your regex as "subarray"
2. Unicode character classes as mentioned by @Casimir in the comments do not exist in `re` module, you can use [a-zA-Z] or `\w` accordingly as a replacement there.

Running code: http://ideone.com/kukNDw

```
import re
myarray = "blahb.blah = myarray({-68,-67,-65,-62,-61,-59,-58,-56,-55,-53,-52,-51,-49,-48,-47,-46,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-39,-38,-37,-36,-35,-34,-33,-32,-31,-30,-29,-29,-28,-27,-26,-26,-25,-24,-24,-23,-22,-22,-21,-21,-20,-20,-19,-19,-19,-18,-18,-18,-17,-17,-17,-16,-16,-16,-15,-15,-15,-14,-14,-14,-14,-13,-13,-13,-12,-12,-12,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-9.7,-9.4,-9.1,-8.8,-8.5,-8.2,-7.9,-7.5,-7.2,-6.9,-6.6,-6.3,-6,-5.7,-5.3,-5,-4.7,-4.4,-4.1,-3.8,-3.4,-3.1,-2.8,-2.5,-2.2,-1.9,-1.6,-1.2,-0.9,-0.6,-0.3,0,0.3,0.6,1,1.3,1.6,1.9,2.2,2.5,2.9,3.2,3.5,3.8,4.1,4.4,4.7,5.1,5.4,5.7,6}, x*456, 1);"

matchObj = re.search( r".+?(=*)(myarray\()\{([\S| \|'.,]*)},\s*(\w+)(.*\*\d+)", myarray)

print matchObj
print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group()
print "matchObj.group(1) : ", matchObj.group(1)
print "matchObj.group(2) : ", matchObj.group(2)
```